# J2EP gives "NullPointerException" when I try to use reverse proxy

Tags: java, reverse-proxy, j2ep

I am using J2EP (its 1.0 stable version) as a reverse proxy server on a websites. First I installed Apache Tomcat to deploy the project, then I made the configurations for reverse proxy. In addition, the server does not support "isRewriting = true", therefore I had to use "RoundRobinCluster".

For example;
If I use such expression,

```
"<server className="net.sf.j2ep.servers.BaseServer" 
    domainName="www.nytimes.com"
    path="/test">  
    <rule className="net.sf.j2ep.rules.AcceptEverythingRule" /> 
</server>"
```

and go to: `http://localhost:8080/test`

no page appears and this leads me to use "RoundRobinCluster", which is;

```
<server className="net.sf.j2ep.servers.RoundRobinCluster">
    <server
        domainName="www.nytimes.com"
        path="/test"
    />
      <rule className="net.sf.j2ep.rules.AcceptEverythingRule" /> 
</server>
```

and go to: `http://localhost:8080/test`

this time I face up with such error;

java.lang.NullPointerException

net.sf.j2ep.ServerChain.evaluate(ServerChain.java:104)
net.sf.j2ep.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:75)

I wasn't expecting such error in a stable version. Or I might have missed something, any help would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I haven't met with j2ep earlier. To find out what happened I looked to SVN on `sourceforge.org`.

Problem code here is:

```
102     while (itr.hasNext() && !currentMatches) {
103     currentContainer = (ServerContainer) itr.next();
104     currentMatches = currentContainer.getRule().matches(request);
105     }
```

.

It seems to you have some `Rule` which wasn't created, may be it had been declared in wrong way. Try to refine rule declaration (check spelling, attributes, etc.) or try to find other errors in log.